# Why gmail app rename csv or doc file name to five digit number when I try to attach from internal storage of android device?

Tags: android, gmail, email-attachments

Why gmail app renames csv or doc file name to five digit number when I try to attach from the internal storage of my mobile. In fact gmail removes the .csv or .doc extension and change the original file name to five digit numbers, in my case the attached file name becomes '29102' instead of 'sample.csv'. Once I download this file (29012) and add .csv extension manually, I can see the original content of the file.  Can anyone explain me why and if I have to make any modifications in my gmail account settings?

Comment: Show your code with used url.

Comment: Questions about topics other than development or programming, but related to Android, are not on-topic here, but may be on-topic at https://android.stackexchange.com.  Please review [what types of questions are on-topic in that community](//android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) before posting there to ensure that your question is on-topic.

Answer (score 0):

@@Ryan, I am developing an app that does file attachment. I encountered this problem from within my app. However, to check first how gmail behaves, I did the attachment directly from gmail and the problem is the same.  I said the problem might be from Android system itself. If you are a developer, you may hint me how you might have solved issues like this